# Score of ANOVA in selected features

Tags: feature-selection, score, anova

I selected features using ANOVA (because I have Numerical data as input and Categorical data as target):

```
anova = SelectKBest(score_func=f_classif, k='all')
anova.fit(X_train, y_train.values.argmax(1)) # y_train.values.argmax(1) because I already one-hot-encoded the target.
```

When I plot the score, it show me the figure in image :

```
plt.xlabel("Number of features selected")
plt.ylabel("Score (nb of correct classifications)")
plt.plot(range(len(anova.scores_)), anova1.scores_)
plt.show()
```

[image]

What does the interpretation of this figure ? why there is some interruption in the plot ?

Comment: What do you mean that you’ve selected features using ANOVA?

Comment: ANOVA is a Feature Selection method, right ?

Comment: ANOVA is a way of testing of multiple groups have the same mean. How do you apply that to feature selection? (I have my ideas, but all that matters is what you did.)

Comment: Dear @Dave Thank you for this information, you could see what I mean by using this method in this link: https://machinelearningmastery.com/feature-selection-with-numerical-input-data/

Answer (score 2):

You have misunderstood what the `anova` returns. It returns a list of importance for each feature.

So, it is **not number of features selected** but should be **index of each feature** in the plot. Thus the confusion clears up.

The plot shows that, for example, 45th feature and 65th feature are more important.

Reference:

1. [SelectKBest](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.SelectKBest.html)